# Move multiple Spawned objects to different positions

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I created a ball prefabs and instantiate it more than 3 times in different points. Is there anyway I could move each ball objects separately without moving them all at once?

Comment: Check out the YouTube tutorials; this is not the place to learn Unity; you may ask about specific errors or problems without asking about the very basics of the Unity engine.

Answer (score 0):

You could add them to a list when you instantiate them, (Or a dictionary, for easier access via script but lacking access in the inspector), and then call functions on them. Like So:

```
GameObject BallOne = Instantiate(ballPrefab, new Vector3(targetX, targetY, targetZ), Quaternion.Identity);
GameObject BallTwo = Instantiate(ballPrefab, new Vector3(targetX, targetY, targetZ), Quaternion.Identity);
GameObject BallThree = Instantiate(ballPrefab, new Vector3(targetX, targetY, targetZ), Quaternion.Identity);
BallList.add(BallOne);
BallList.add(BallTwo);
BallList.add(BallThree);
```

Then, you can access them individually like this:

```
BallList[0].transform.position += new Vector3(1,1,1);
```

Hope that Helps!

If you wanted to do it with a for loop, (and don't need to access the balls by name), Do it like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
  GameObject newBall = Instantiate(ballPrefab, new Vector3(targetX, targetY, targetZ), Quaternion.Identity)
//If you need to tweak the positions, make a list of Vector3's and instead of having new Vector3(), do VectorList[i]
BallList.add(newBall);
}
```

Access data same as before.

Comment: There is probably a quicker way to do this using for loops, but I do not recall it.

Comment: Please tell me.

Comment: How did that work out?

Comment: I'm working on it now. I've been so busy away from my PC. Thanks for taking your time to help me out 

Comment: It works, the only problem is that that all spawn at once, but I wanted each one of them to spawn every two seconds

Comment: Ouh, to get them to spawn at an interval with this, use Time.DeltaTime, learn coroutines, or use InvokeRepeating.